# Assign a task to particular alfresco user based on value of variable/condition inside .bpmn2 file

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Greetings to the community! I am using alfresco community edition 6.0.0 with the embedded activiti workflow engine. I have already created some users and I would like to create and deploy a .bpmn2 file which will describe the following workflow-scenario:

"Concerning the value of variable 'X', assign this task to this user".

The process of my bpmn2 file has currently this structure

```
<process isExecutable="true" id="example" name="example Activiti process">
    <startEvent id="start"
        activiti:formKey="wf:submitAdhocTask" />
    <sequenceFlow id='flow1' 
        sourceRef='start'
        targetRef='task1' />

    <userTask id="task1" name="The first task"
        activiti:formKey="wf:task1">
        <documentation> 
             The user assigned to this task will be decided according to the value of a variable
        </documentation>
       <extensionElements>
           <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string>

                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
           </activiti:taskListener>
       </extensionElements>
        <humanPerformer>
            <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}</formalExpression>
            </resourceAssignmentExpression>
        </humanPerformer>
    </userTask>

    <sequenceFlow id='flow3' sourceRef='task2'
        targetRef='theEnd' />

    <endEvent id="theEnd" />
```

I want to achieve the following scenario:

> if(X < 5 ) { assign task1 to userA} else { assign task1 to userB}

My questions are the following:

1) Where to set this variable? I have created one using the workflow console:

```
var bpm:X*=5
```

2) How to use the above variable in order to implement my scenario?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the following to my activiti taskListener

```
 <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string>
                  if (bpm_Y == 5 ) task.assignee = 'userA';
                  if (bpm_Y != 5)  task.assignee = 'userB';
                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
           </activiti:taskListener>
```

and passing the variable on the start process like 'start bpm:Y=10 '

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating that expression:
${bean.function(X)}

where bean.function(X) returns the user that should be assigned based on your business logic in this case the if(X < 5) .

Regarding setting the variable, you set the variable when you start the process or in any User or Service task before the one where you need that logic. You don't really need: activiti:taskListener

Comment: Consider the following scenario, i start my workflow from alfresco workflow console with the commant "start bpm:varY=5"  and  inside my bpmn i want to have inside my 

 <humanPerformer>
                <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                    <formalExpression>${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}</formalExpression>
                </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </humanPerformer> 

something like: "if bpm_varY > 5" ---> userA else ----> userB instead of 
${bpm_assignee.properties.userName} which i currently use and pass as a parameter on start